# Can't run wave engine app in my visualstudio

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2012

I'm not sure if the title is correct, but don't know what whould the title be.

I'm developing a minigame with some friends using `waveengine`, but, while the code works for them (we share the code using a bitbucket git repo), I keep getting the same error:

```
SharpDXException
HRESULT: [0x80040154], Module: [Unknown], ApiCode: [Unknown/Unknown], Message: Class not registered
```

I don't modify the code anyway, but it won't work for me while it does work for my friends.

Any idea?

PS: It's my very first time using wave, so I might have skipped some configuration, but cannot find what by myself